# Local notifications not adjusting for timezones

Tags: ios

I'm scheduling a local notification with an NSDate with the time set to 9pm and am setting the  notification's timezone to UTC/GMT.

If I set the device timezone to UTC (and time to 8.59pm) then the notification fires at 9pm as expected.

However if I set the device timezone to West Coast US (i.e. set it to Seattle or Cupertino or PDT directly etc.) and set the time to 1.59pm, or set the device timezone to East Coast US and set the time to 4.59pm, then the notification does not fire at 2pm or 5pm respectively.

But I was expecting it should do because  when it is 9pm UTC then with the current daylight saving at this time of year 9pm UTC is equivalent to 5pm Eastern and 2pm Western.

If I set the time on the device to 8.59pm while the device timezone is PDT then the notification will fire at 9pm, even though I have set the timezone in the notification to UTC/GMT, this is not correct because 9pm PDT is not 9pm UTC.

Therefore it seems to me the OS is ignoring the notification's timezone that I am setting.
Does anybody have any explanation why its not working as expected?

Thanks

Comment: You sound right, it seems that once the notification is registered with the OS, it's first time is set to a the relative time according to the device timezone. 

After if you change the time it seems that the OS doesn't update it's fire data register.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the documentation of the  `timeZone` property of `UILocalNotification`:

> ... If you assign a valid NSTimeZone object to this property, the fire
>   date is interpreted as a wall-clock time that is automatically
>   adjusted when there are changes in time zones; an example suitable for
>   this case is an an alarm clock.

So I assume that if you want an absolute time for the notification, you must *not* assign a time zone.

Comment: Thank you! I was experiencing this same issue, and removing the time zone resolved my problem; however, is there any (known) adverse side affects of removing the time zone property from notifications?

Comment: For instance: if removing the time zone, and daylights savings occurs, will the notification still fire at the proper time?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem be the case for daylight savings change. I have some repeating notifications with the timezone set to the localTimeZone but since this last weekend when the clocks went forward an hour they are firing an hour later, ie at 19:00 instead of 18:00.

Seems like when I schedule an event I will have to determine the timezone for that date and use that.

Thanks

Comment: Yep, I found the same thing as well. You need to set the time using NSDateComponents, not by adding a time interval.

Comment: Yes, I did - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782350/uilocationnotification-not-obeying-daylight-savings/15837550#15837550 apologies for not updating this item