# UILocationNotification not obeying daylight savings

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am scheduling local notifications like so

```
+ (void) addLocalNotification: (Event *) event {
  UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
  localNotif.fireDate = event.scheduleTime;
  localNotif.alertBody = @"Time to apply drops\nPlease press view to see details";
  localNotif.soundName = ALARM_SOUND_FILE;
  localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
  localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
  NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:event.number,LN_EVENT_KEY,  ACTION_EVENT, LN_ACTION_KEY,  nil];
  localNotif.userInfo = dict;
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
}
```

However after the clocks went forward this last weekend, the notifications scheduled before the clocks went forward are firing an hour later, ie 19:00 instead of 18:00

The apple documentation says to get "wall clock" time set the time zone as above.

Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: And `event.scheduleTime` is the correct NSDate for localTimeZone?

Comment: No - On further inspection, the code that does the future scheduling is not daylight savings enabled I realise. It was just adding twenty four hours and not using the date formatter to get the correct GMT time - sorry

Comment: I can not post the answer yet, have to wait another seven hours, sigghhh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So rather than adding a time interval of 24 hours I have used ..

```
+ (NSDate *) addOneDayToDate: (NSDate *) date {
   return [currentCalendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDay toDate:date options:0];
}
```

where

```
 oneDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
 [oneDay setDay:1];
 currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
```

This works in most cases unless the date is between midnight and the time the clocks change usually around 2:00am. Have not needed logic for this since the date times will be after this.